# Kivy porting to iOS. Opening a file works while writing to a file does not

Tags: python, ios, file, save, kivy

The reset save gives the error message "IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

```
def reset_save(self):
    try:
        file = open("./save.txt", "rw+")
    except:
        print("Wrong when saving to file.")
    else:
        for n in self.highscore:
            file.write('0' + '\n')
        self.highscore = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        file.close()
```

the "rw+" was changed from "w" from the android version, using "w" prints out "Wrong when saving to file". The android version works with no problem using this code.

There are no problems with the get_save in either versions

```
def get_save(self):
    try:
        file = open("./save.txt", "r")
    except:
        print("Wrong when opening file.")
    else:
        n = 0
        for line in file:
            self.highscore[n] = float(line)
            n += 1
        file.close()
```

The reset_save is used to write 10 lines of zeros, resetting the highscore list.

The get_save takes the lines in the save.txt and puts them into a list

I used the kivy guide to port from android to iOS. It is building via Xcode. The rest of of the game works the same as on the android version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all directory on all platform when your application are is writable. On iOS, all application are sandboxed, and the directory where the application lives is not writable. But that's not the case on Android.
Reading will work because i guess you're shipping a default save.txt file. You should not to, and create it if not exist when the application starts.

If you want to save a file, save it in [App.user_data_dir](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.user_data_dir). Here is an example of your `reset_save` function, reworked:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from os.path import join

def reset_save(self):
    user_data_dir = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir
    filename = join(user_data_dir, "save.txt")
    try:
         self.highscore = [0] * 10
         with open(filename, "w") as fd:
             for n in self.highscore:
                 fd.write('0' + '\n')
    except:
         Logger.exception("Cannot reset save file")
```

Comment: Thank you a ton! I've one very small correction: instead of file.write('0' + '\n'), fd.write('0' + '\n') was needed.